# Ошибка при регистрации пользователя

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Делаю небольшое приложения, используя гайд пытаюсь добавить регистрацию с авторизацией используя `spring data jpa`, при попытке зарегистрироваться выдаёт ошибку:

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException`: ОШИБКА: `INSERT` или `UPDAT`E в таблице `"t_users_roles"` нарушает ограничение внешнего ключа `"fk21o0fjfnxuak26bc3kqfkyr6f"` Подробности: `Ключ (roles_id)=(1)` отсутствует в таблице `"t_role"`.

Не могу понять в чём дело, вот код классов `User` и `Role`:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_users")
public class User implements UserDetails {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        @Size(min=2, message = "Не меньше 2 знаков")
        private String username;
        @Size(min=2, message = "Не меньше 2 знаков")
        private String password;
        @Transient
        private String passwordConfirm;
        @Email
        @Size(max = 40, message = "Длина email не должна превышать 40 символов")
        private String email;
        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private Set<Role> roles;

        public User() {
        }

        public String getEmail() {
                return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
                this.email = email;
        }

        public Long getId() {
                return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
                this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public String getUsername() {
                return username;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
                return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
                return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
                return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
                return true;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
                this.username = username;
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
                return getRoles();
        }

        @Override
        public String getPassword() {
                return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
                this.password = password;
        }

        public String getPasswordConfirm() {
                return passwordConfirm;
        }

        public void setPasswordConfirm(String passwordConfirm) {
                this.passwordConfirm = passwordConfirm;
        }

        public Set<Role> getRoles() {
                return roles;
        }

        public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
                this.roles = roles;
        }
}

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_role")
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Transient
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users;
    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Role(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return getName();
    }
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться

Comment: Так в ошибке же все написано. Вы добавляете юзера с ролью. Но такой роли нет. Вам нужно сначала создать роль в таблице t_role

Comment: @Adm123 Спасибо, тупанул